# How do I see stdout when running Django tests?

Tags: python, django, debugging, testing, stdout

When I run tests with `./manage.py test`, whatever I send to the standard output through `print` doesn't show. When tests fail, I see an "stdout" block per failed test, so I guess Django traps it (but doesn't show it when tests pass).

Comment: You should mark you own answer as correct since it is.

Comment: my Django ver 1.11 printss everything, without any `-s` or `--no-input`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Checked `TEST_RUNNER` in `settings.py`, it's using a project-specific runner that calls out to Nose. *Nose has the `-s` option to stop it from capturing `stdout`*, but if I run:

`./manage.py test -s`

`manage.py` captures it first and throws a "no such option" error. The help for `manage.py` doesn't mention this, but I found that if I run:

`./manage.py test -- -s`

it ignores the `-s` and lets me capture it on the custom runner's side, passing it to Nose without a problem.

Comment: Because I am using the contrib.sites framework, I specify --settings for my tests. When I do that, -s flag functions as expected, and passing in another -- before the -s throws an OSError (No such file -s).

Comment: Just for the record. If you have django_south installed in INSTALLED_APPS __after__ django_nose it won't let you give options for nose (like -s). You need to put south __before__ django_nose in INSTALLED_APPS. It was the issue with me

Comment: Oddly this seems to work for me with `print(...)`, but the output of pretty print with `pprint.pprint(...)` does not show in the console.

Comment: For me adding -s worked pretty fine, as I am advised not to play with the settings.py file.

Comment: didn't work for me why are so basic things so hard in python

Comment: may try "./manage.py test --" without "-s"

Answer (score 43):

Yeah, this issue is caused by `NoseTestSuiteRunner`. Adding `-- -s` is tricky and not the best solution.
Try to add the following lines in the `settings.py`:

```
NOSE_ARGS = ['--nocapture',
             '--nologcapture',]
```

This solved my problems.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `-- -s` method causes undesired side effects.

Answer (score 28):

There are several levels of verbosity available which affects the amount of details we see:
You can try:

```
python manage.py test -v 2
```

Other levels available are:

- `-v 0` : Least amount of details
- `-v 1`: Default
- `-v 2` : More details e.g. print statements included.

Comment: This one is way more convenient, than playing with loggers, thanks!

Comment: aka `--verbosity` (long name of the same argument)

Answer (score 6):

Using current versions of all the relevant packages  (`Django==1.11.2`, `django-nose==1.4.5` and `nose==1.3.7`) it is sufficient to add the `--nocapture` flag when running your tests. Thus a simple

```
./manage.py test --nocapture
```

will suffice.

Granted of course that you have

```
TEST_RUNNER = "django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner"
```

in your `settings.py`

Answer (score 4):

You probably have some intermediate test runner, such as Nose, intercepting and storing stdout. Try either running the Django tests directly, or write to stderr instead.

Comment: You were right. Running the django tests directly doesn't work because there's a lot of settings things up that the custom runner does, but I was able to trace the problem and fix it. Now this is my first question here, so is it ok to edit the question to include the solution like above? Thanks!

Comment: The best thing is to post your own answer.

Comment: This is not always the case, I have encountered situations where you get this behaviour without nose. I don't have a solution but i think this answer is incomplete.