# How to debug Django unit tests?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, debugging, django-unittest

I have a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) unit test, and I want to put print statements in it for debugging purposes but apparently django is suppressing them. How else can I print the value of a variable? I may be able to hack around with asserts, etc. but wondering how people do this.

Comment: You might try looking at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way

Comment: The answer lies in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236285/how-do-i-see-stdout-when-running-django-tests

Comment: Have you tried [`pytest`](https://pytest.org/en/latest/)? It modifies the `assert` statement and prints the variables in the assertion for you, if a test fails.

Answer (score 8):

You just can increase the verbosity with `-v 3`

Answer (score 0):

just use the assert* methods:

```
self.assertEqual("the valule you want to know", 0)
```

Comment: hard to believe django makes something so basic so hard