# Logging not showing in console during django tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, logging

I am trying some simple tests in django. I have setup my django logging system in my settings file. But when I run my test it won't print debug messages on my console. This happens when I run tests from manage.py test command. If I use my IDE's run command It prints the messages normally. My logging setup is the following

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d (thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple':{
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG'

        },
        'payments_system': {
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        }
    }
}
```

Logging is based on django's website example. How can I make messages appear in the console when I run tests with manage.py?

Comment: May see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236285/how-do-i-see-stdout-when-running-django-tests, django's testrunner seems to capture stdout, so your logging messages might get swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

I have [Django logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/) set up to log to a file, like this:

```
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
    },
},
```

When I run tests with `python manage.py test`, the logs also go to that file.

Since you're using a `console` handler, your logs are should be going to `stdout`, which is likely being captured filtered by the test code. So try using a [`FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) instead. Refer to the first example under [Configuring Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) for more details.